# how to pass schema_name_variable in stored procedure syntax "call <<schema_name_variable>>.storedproceduretask()

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I am trying to pass the schema name as a variable in the stored procedure syntax (CALL schema_name_var.sp_master_procedure();-> full code given below). But this code fails when I try to run in redshift. Could somebody provide a solution on how can I achieve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE master_work_se.sp_master_table_automation()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS '
    DECLARE
      schema_name_var nvarchar(max) = 'master_work_se';

        BEGIN
          CALL schema_name_var.sp_master_procedure();
        END;

    END;
    ';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE format('CALL %I.sp_master_procedure()', schema_name_var);
```

Comment: Thank you. converting the syntax of call procedure to string and using EXECUTE solved my problem.